# Unique factorization of finite groups under direct sum?

Tags: gr.group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

I am told that finite groups have unique factorization under direct product.  That is, call a nontrivial group "indivisible" if it is not isomorphic to a direct product of nontrivial groups.  Then every finite group can be "factored" (by direct product) into a unique collection of indivisible groups.

In particular, if $G$ and $H$ are finite groups so that $G\times G\cong H\times H$, then $G\cong H$.

Can anyone provide a reference to a proof of these results?  What is known in the infinite case?  Thanks.

Comment: Recent related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45668/is-the-decomposition-of-an-algebra-into-irreducible-components-essentially-unique .  Uniqueness of roots among finite structures with one-element substructures was proven by Lovasz, along with a cancellation theorem.  For infinite structures, check some of the references.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.11.19

Comment: Btw, a term often used in a case like this is "directly irreducible": Start with a category $C$ with finite products and call an object of $C$ _directly irreducible_ if it is neither a terminal object nor isomorphic to the product (in $C$) of two non-terminal objects. In fact, this is a special case of a much more general definition of "irreducible": The isomorphism (iso) classes of $C$ form a commutative monoid $\mathcal V(C)$ under the binary operation that maps a pair $(\mathfrak a, \mathfrak b)$ of iso classes to the iso class of the product $A \prod B$ for some $A \in \mathfrak a$ [...]

Comment: [...] and $B \in \mathfrak b$ (the universal property of products implies that this is a well-defined operation). But in a monoid $H$ (written multiplicatively) we do have a natural notion of irreducible: It is an element $a \in H$ such that (i) $a$ is a $\mid_H$-non-unit, i.e., $a \nmid_H 1_H$ (where $\mid_H$ is the divisibility preorder on $H$, i.e., $x\mid_H y$ means that $x\in H$ and $y\in HxH$) and (ii) if $a\ne bc$ for all $\mid_H$-non-units $b, c$ such that $a\nmid_H b$ and $a \nmid_H c$. In particular, the $\mid_{\mathcal V(C)}$-irreducibles are the directly irreducible objects of $C$.

Comment: I think "directly indecomposable" is a common terminology, possibly more self-explanatory. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507366) (in French) contains a number of references on these issues.

Comment: @YCor Maybe so, but the term "irreducible" seems more in line with a certain general philosophy (see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_ring).

Comment: @SalvoTringali I feel the contrary. For instance for a nonzero representation, irreducible means "no nonzero subrep" while indecomposable means "not direct sum of two nonzero subrep", which sounds closer. Thus "irreducible group" would be closer in spirit to a simple group. Anyway these are distinct objects so there is no definite best/canonical choice of terminology. In any case one can look at the existing terminology in the references of my paper linked in my previous message.

Comment: @YCor Irreducible polyomials and, more generally, irreducible elements in a ring (or at least in some rings) have been studied under this name for a long time, and all these things _do_ fit in the same general framework. But yes, there is a similar 'issue' also with 'indecomposable modules' and 'irreducible modules' (and it's something often coming up in the discussion in some circles). All these 'issues' are, however, wiped away if one looks at them from a different perspective. (Thanks for mentioning your paper with de la Harpe.)

Comment: @SalvoTringali A polynomial $P(t)$ is irreducible iff the $k[t]$-module $k[t]/(P(t))$ is simple — i.e. defines an irreducible representation (well, of the algebra $k[t]$ itself). This module is indecomposable iff $P$ is a power of an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: @YCor Do you mean that this characterization of irred polynomials is the reason why irreps are called like that? If so, cool! But I'm not sure to get your point: I thought we were discussing which term ('irreducible' vs 'indecomposable') _would_ be, in a sense, more appropriate (partly based on historical evidence and background) to describe a certain property that shows up in different forms (in many areas), although the essence is ultimately the same. Maybe '_would have_ been' would be a better phrasing here: I suspect it's now too late to fix the 'issue' one way or the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About the first fact see [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Direct_product_is_cancellative_for_finite_groups) page (the Krull–Remak–Schmidt theorem). For infinite (even finitely generated) groups the situation is different because there exists an infinite f.g. group isomorphic to its [direct square.](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_isomorphic_to_its_square)

**Update.** [Hirshon](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01229716), found two non-isomorphic finitely generated nilpotent (infinite) groups $G,H$ such that $G\times G\cong H\times H$.

Comment: To add to Mark's answer, there are finite groups $G\not\cong H$ with ${\mathbb Z}\times G\cong{\mathbb Z}\times H$, so for infinite groups the situation is rather grim.

Comment: @Tim: I did not know that. What are these $G$ and $H$? I think that if $G$ is finite, then it is exactly the set of all torsion elements in ${\mathbb Z}\times G$. So $G$ must be isomorphic to $H$ if ${\mathbb Z}\times G\cong {\mathbb Z}\times H$. But perhaps I am wrong and do not see something obvious. 

Comment: @Tim: Perhaps it was a misprint and you meant "infinite" instead of "finite"?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant "infinite" $G$ and $H$. Thank you, Mark! I'll try to remember the example and post it here, it was something reasonably simple.

Comment: @Tim: It is proved here: http://www.springerlink.com/content/k7p548016pvq0163/ . There, $G$ and $H$ are finitely generated and nilpotent. 

Comment: Hirshon also proves that there are two non-isomorphic f.g. nilpotent groups $G,H$ such that the $n$th power of $G$ is isomorphic to the $n$th power of $H$ for some $n$.

Comment: I added it to my answer. 

Comment: @Mark: One simple example is $G=C_{11}\rtimes{\mathbb Z}$ with the generator of ${\mathbb Z}$ acting as $x\mapsto x^2$ and $H=C_{11}\rtimes{\mathbb Z}$ with the generator of ${\mathbb Z}$ acting as $x\mapsto x^7$. Then ${\mathbb Z}\times G\cong{\mathbb Z}\times H$ but $G\not\cong H$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Tim: It is interesting because your groups are virtually cyclic. But why is that true? If your example is true, then one can get two non-isomorphic virtually cyclic groups (your $G, H$) such that $G^n\cong H^n$ for some $n$ but $G\not\cong H$ by the result of Hirshon. Hirshon, by the way, also proves that two nilpotent groups with infinite cyclic centers cannot have isomorphic direct powers. Of course your groups are not nilpotent, but they do have infinite cyclic centers. 

Comment: @Mark: The $C_{11}$ is unique in $G$ (torsion subgroup), and the quotient $G/C_{11}\cong Z$ has two canonical elements (generators), $\pm1\in Z$. They act by $2,2^{-1}=6\in(Z/11Z)^\times$ on $C_{11}$. For $H$, the corresponding pair of numbers is different, $7,7^{-1}=8\in(Z/11Z)^\times$, so $G\not\cong H$. The important thing is that both $2$ and $7$ generate the whole of $(Z/11Z)^\times$, so the image of the action is the same subgroup. Otherwise $G\times Z\cong H\times Z$ has no chance to work... 

Comment: ...Now $G\times Z=C_{11}\rtimes (Z\times Z)$ with the two generators $e_1, e_2$ of $Z\times Z$ acting by conjugation as $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto x$. Choose another basis of $Z\times Z$, say $f_1=7e_1+2e_2, f_2=10e_1+3e_2$. The determinant of this transformation is 7*3-2*10=1, so it is a basis. Then $f_1$ and $f_2$ act by $x\mapsto x^{2^7}=x^7$ and $x\mapsto x^{2^{10}}=x$, so $G\times Z\cong (C_{11}\rtimes \langle f_1\rangle)\times \langle f_2\rangle\cong H\times Z$, as promised. (To make a long story short, an extra $Z$ keeps the action image but may mess up the generators.)

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46686/unique-factorization-of-finite-groups-under-direct-sum/46690#comment112495_46690) above is broken. It points to a paper by Hirshon, and a working link is added in the post itself.